# connecting to socket.io server doesn't work when it's via Websocket()

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

This code works great and connects to the socket server that I have running:

```
 var socket = io('http://localhost:8888');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    socket.emit('evento', { my: 'data' });
  });
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
   console.log('user disconnected');
  });
socket.on('connect', function () {
   console.log('user connect');
var data = 'ddsds';
       socket.emit('evento', { my: 'data' });


  });
```

On the other hand when I try to use `WebSocket()` it fails to connect. This is the code that doesn't work:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8888');
// Open the socket
socket.onopen = function(event) {

    // Send an initial message
    socket.send('I am the client and Im listening!');

}

    // Listen for messages
    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log('Client received a message',event);
    };

    // Listen for socket closes
    socket.onclose = function(event) {
        console.log('Client notified socket has closed',event);
    };
    socket.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log('error: ',event);
    };
```

It's not an error in the code; I think there is a different way to connect. I need this to work using `WebSocket();`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.io` is something that runs on top of WebSocket (using WebSocket as one of the transports it supports).  It adds new semantics on top of WebSocket so you can't use the `socket.io` methods and events directly with a WebSocket object.

`socket.io` will select the WebSocket transport if it is available so you should not need to use your second example - the first should work just fine and will use WebSockets automatically (when available).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9015260/816620) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14589826/816620) for how to use the minimized, gzipped and cached version of socket.io which makes it smaller and faster.

Comment: yeah the issue is socket.io is ~60kb, and use websockets directly will save well about 60kb. On the server side I like running socket.io. site gets over 2000 concurrent or more throughout the day and we try to make the pages load as fast as we can.

Comment: @stacknoob - You should switch to the minimized version of socket.io which is smaller: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9015260/816620.  No matter what your issue is, you can't use the socket.io interface with just a plain WebSocket and none of the socket.io code.

Comment: @stacknoob - per http://stackoverflow.com/a/14589826/816620, you can also enable gzip and browser caching.  With minification and these two enabled, it's a lot lot smaller.

Comment: thanks jfriend00.I am using the minified one. but yeah I ended up using socket.io client as per your advice